# Some packages not visible even after adding <queries> tag to AndroidManifest.xml (Android 12 device)

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, android-12

I have implemented some code in my app in order to get a list of accessibility services installed on my device using `AccessibilityManager.getInstalledAccessibilityServiceList`. Since devices running Android 11 and above are subjected to [package visibility filtering](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#intent-filter-signature), I added a `<queries>` tag in my manifest like this:

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent>
</queries>
```

Unfortunately there are one or two installed accessibility services that are still not showing up but I can see them from the Accessibility menu in my device settings screen (like the ones belonging to [com.dashlane](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dashlane) and [Voice Access](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess)).

I have checked that these missing accessibility services do show up correctly if I declare the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission in my app's manifest instead of using the `<queries>` tag to get visibility to installed apps, so this seems like a package visibility filtering issue. Does anyone know why the `<queries>` tag is somehow filtering out these missing packages and their accessibility services?

Comment: That does not look like a normal `Intent` action string. Where did you come up with it? Is it documented the every `AccessibilityService` will have an `<intent-filter>` using that action string?

Comment: @CommonsWare I got the `<intent-filter>` declaration from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#declaration). This other [page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#service-declaration) also mentions that it is necessary for an `AccessibilityService` (deployed on Android 1.6 or higher), thus I understood it as every accessibility service would have an intent filter using that action string and I could use it to filter for packages that have accessibility services implemented.

Comment: I agree, that does look good. "there are one or two installed accessibility services that are still not showing up" -- when you say "installed", do you mean ones installed by you? Or are they pre-installed? If they are pre-installed, it is possible that the device manufacturer has these accessibility options baked into the OS, and so they are not packages that `PackageManager` might find.

Comment: Yes they were installed by me and I could uninstall them completely too. (both app and accessibility service removed) The unusual thing is that `PackageManager` was able to find these accessibility if I declared the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission or if I used another action string like `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`. Thus I'm not sure if the problem is with the `AccessibilityService` action string's behaviour or if it is due to some other setting elsewhere..

Comment: Install [this app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.oF2pks.applicationsinfo/) (also available on the Play Store IIRC) and examine the manifest of the two apps that are not showing up as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it was not working may be because the accessibility service of the apps that are not showing up is not exported (`android:exported="false"`) in the manifest, which interfered with the output somehow.

For example:

```
<service android:enabled="@bool/is_accessibility_supported" android:exported="false" android:name="com.random.name.AccessibilityService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_meta"/>
</service>
```

The workaround is to use a combination of some other  tags in the manifest like `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`, or as mentioned in the question, to declare the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission.